# how to do lightning component backup into our LOCAL SYSTEM or in salesforce .?

Tags: lightning-aura-components

how to do lightning component backup into our LOCAL SYSTEM or in salesforce ?

Comment: are you asking how lightning components store data in database?

Comment: to store lightning component in my local system

Comment: Okay, you mean retrieving code in your local machine?

Comment: yes @PranayJaiswal

Answer (score 4):

You can use any IDE to fetch data from Salesforce environment.
The simplest would be to use Force.com IDE(https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.eclipse.meta/eclipse/ide_getting_started.htm)

That being said, if you don't want to install any IDE, you can use the workbench to retrieve lightning components.

1. Create a new file name as package.xml
2. The content of package.xml will be the one below.

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
   <types>
       <members>*</members>
       <name>AuraDefinitionBundle</name>
   </types>
   <version>44.0</version>
   ```
3. Go to https://workbench.developerforce.com, login with your org, then click on Migration Tab then Retrieve.

   4. In Unpackaged Manifest , from file explorer select the package.xml and tick single package and click retreive.

It will retreive all your lightning component code in downloadable zip file.

Comment: In addition to @PranayJaiswal's answer,  you can use also use [Ant Migration Tool](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.daas.meta/daas/meta_development.htm) - this would help you get and deploy metadata. Also, the latest and better IDE is the VS Code with [Salesforce Extensions](https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/extension_vscode) - it is more complicated to use than eclipse, but if you anyway start learning today - maybe it is best to start with this